# Unable to render template with data set in setupController

Tags: ember.js

Emberjs v1.0.0-pre.4

Handlebars 1.0.0.rc.2

I'm building a facebook friend list manager in ember. When I navigate to `list/1/members` the data that  MembersRoute populates MembersController with is not appearing.

The MembersRoute will render the friends template, which normally displays all our friends, but in this scenario only the members of the selected list.

The application's router

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('instructions');
    this.route('friends');
    this.route('members', {path: '/list/:list_id/members'});
});
```

The route

```
App.MembersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        var list = this.controllerFor('application').get('selectedList'),
            friends = list && list.get('members') || [];
        return friends;
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        var list = this.controllerFor('application').get('selectedList');
        controller.set('title', list.get('title'));
        controller.set('list', list);
        controller.set('content', model);
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render('friends');
    }
});
```

The friends template

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='friends'>
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <ul id='friends'>
    {{#each friend in controller}}
      <a href='#' {{action 'select' friend}}>
        <li {{bindAttr class='friend.isSelected:selected'}}>
            <img {{bindAttr src='friend.imageUrl'}}/>
            <p>{{friend.name}}</p>
        </li>
      </a>
    {{else}}
      <h3>There are no friends in this list.</h3>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

Application template

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>
      <div class='row'>
          <div class='span4'>
              {{render 'lists'}}
          </div>
          <div class='span8>
              {{outlet}}
          </div>
      </div>
</script>
```

Lastly, the data store and models

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.List = DS.Model.extend({
    members: DS.hasMany('App.Friend'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    isSelected: DS.attr('boolean'),
    num_of_members: function () {
        var num = this.get('members').toArray().length,
        str = num + ' Member';
        return num === 1 ? str : str + 's';
    }.property('members'),
    title: function () {
        return 'Friends in ' + this.get('name');
    }.property('name'),
    toggleSelected: function () {
        this.set('isSelected', !this.get('isSelected'));
        return this;
    }
});

App.Friend = DS.Model.extend({
    lists: DS.hasMany('App.List'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    imageUrl: DS.attr('string'),
    isSelected: DS.attr('boolean'),
    toggleSelected: function () {
        this.set('isSelected', !this.get('isSelected'));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

really you should just use the _super to implement the default implementation.

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model)
  controller.set('something', 'some value');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but it looks like `model` is ignored or lost when `setupController` is defined. I don't know if this is a bug with EmberJS.

My workaround is to set the model directly:

```
model: function() {
   return this.modelFor('todos');
}
```

Can be extended by:

```
setupController: function(controller) {
  controller.set('something', 'some value');
  controller.set('model', this.modelFor('todos'));    // this was originally in the model function
}
```

Or even better:

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('something', 'some value');
  controller.set('model', model);    // this was originally in the model function
}
```